# How do I return an error message with format.js and update my UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `index.html.erb`, I have this partial rendering like this:

```
<div class="card-comments">
    <%= render partial: "nodes/comment", collection: node.comments.order(created_at: :desc) %>
</div>
```

That partial - `_comment.html.erb` - looks like this:

```
<div id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
  <%= comment.message %> | <%= comment.user.name %> | <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %><br />
</div>
```

My `CommentsController#Create` action looks like this:

```
  def create
    @node = Node.find(params[:node_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.node = @node
    @card_id = params[:card_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save and @node.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

As you can see, this just renders `js` only, so that calls this `create.js.erb`:

```
$("#<%= @card_id %> .card-comments").prepend("<%= j (render partial: 'nodes/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
$("#card-input-field-<%= @card_id %>").val('');
```

This is my comment model with the rules:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :message, message: "You can't submit an empty comment."

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :node, counter_cache: true

  def type?
    "Comment"
  end
end
```

So all of that works wonderfully in the case when there is a valid comment (i.e. it doesn't invalidate any of my validation rules). However, I want to be able to handle errors gracefully.

When validation rule is violated, say entering a blank comment, it returns this error in the server.log but does nothing in the UI:

```
Started POST "/nodes/101/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 00:56:30 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"message"=>""}, "card_id"=>"card-2", "node_id"=>"101"}
  User Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
  Role Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Node Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 101]]
   (1.1ms)  BEGIN
   (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered nodes/_comment.html.erb (21.5ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (23.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 325ms (ActiveRecord: 51.2ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass:
  actionview (4.1.12) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:74:in `distance_of_time_in_words'
  actionview (4.1.12) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:153:in `time_ago_in_words'
  app/views/nodes/_comment.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_nodes__comment_html_erb___2666929257313190166_70115251186960'
  actionview (4.1.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
```

So, what I want to happen is, whenever an error occurs, I want it to tell the user in the UI (I guess in the `create.js.erb`) what the issue was.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use a combination of flash[:error] and the unobtrusive_flash gem

Comment: @lulalala If I can help it, I would rather just do it by hand...nah mean?

Answer (score 1):

```html
Use @comment or @node in create.js.erb to check if there are errors or not. Like to check validation error:

  <% if @comment.errors.present? %>

    //validation error change you ui here

  <% else %>

    //Success, change you ui here

  <% end %>
```